# Using List/Set in If Statement

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, list, set

Pretty basic question (I think), but after searching for a few hours and trying different things I can't seem to find a solution. Pretty new to Apex, but I do have experience in SQL, Java/C#, and Python so nothing is too foreign to me.

In my trigger on Opportunity I'm doing a check on whether or not the Opportunity Owner belongs to a few specific UserRoleIds. This was my original try:

// Step 1. Create list of Users where the UserRole Name has AE or CM in it
// I originally did this by querying the UserRole object and then the User role but realized that was redundant

```
List<User> listUsers = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name like '%AE%' OR UserRole.Name like '%CM%'];
```

// other code

```
for (Opportunity opp : trigger.New) {
// other stuff

if (/*I want to see if opp.OwnerId is in that list/set/SOQL query that I created*/)
```

My understanding is that you can't really do that type of search on a list in that scenario, so I did something where I converted my list to a set. Problem there is I couldn't figure out how to convert `List<User>` or `Set<User>` to `Set<Id>` and then use `set.contains(opp.OwnerId)`.

**My two questions**

1. Can I search if opp.OwnerId is found in a list (either a list of Users or a list of Ids)?
2. If not, how do I convert a SOQL query/list into the proper Set type; i.e. a Set of Ids or Strings, so that I could then use the contains method?

   I hope that was clear, but I'm trying to understand this at a higher/conceptual level rather than just getting the right code for this specific example.

I suppose another thing to ask is if it's possible to save a SOQL query in a list of Ids or Strings rather than the object you're querying?

Thanks so much!

Dylan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think perhaps the best way is to search if the `opp.OwnerId` is in a `Map<User>` that you can create from the result of your query.

```
Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name like '%AE%' OR UserRole.Name like '%CM%']);
```

Now you can iterate the opportunities and use `containsKey()` on the map to see if the User is the owner.

```
for (Opportunity opp : trigger.New) { 
    if (userMap.containsKey(opp.OwnerId)){
        //opp owner is one of your users with the specific role
    }
}
```

There are a number of cool things you can do converting to and from Lists, Sets and Maps. You can use the `addAll()` method on a List or a Set, `Map.containsKey()`, `Map.values()` and `Map.keySet()` among other things.

Have a look at the official documentation for [Maps](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm), [Lists](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm) and [Sets](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm)

Comment: ha ha i jus started typing & u r already there ... boom... :-)

Comment: heh - I was going to edit the question, but thought... maybe I'll just answer first ;). But you get the karma points.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Made the change and my entire trigger worked perfectly. Funny thing was I remember reading about Maps as the way to move my SOQL queries outside my for loop, and after trying that for a bit I moved to using lists/sets (which actually helped me simplify things a bit more). Anyways thanks so much for the quick solution!!

Comment: No worries. I try to use sets and lists as much as possible too, but there are times when Maps are handy!